# how to verify user on sign up using mobile otp in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

my urls.py
'''

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('enter_otp',views.otp_call,name='otp_confirmed')    
]'''
```

my views.py

'''

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST["username"]
        last_name = request.POST["last_name"]
        first_name = request.POST["first_name"]
        date_of_birth = request.POST["birthday"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        Phone = request.POST["phone"]
        gender = request.POST["gender"]
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            messages.info(request,'username already taken')
            return render(request,"signup.html")
        if User.objects.filter(phone_no=Phone).exists():
            messages.error(request,'Phone number already in use')
            return render(request,"signup.html")
        else:
            sent = otp()
            print(sent)
            return otp_call(un=username,pswrd= password,mail = email, fn=first_name,ln=last_name,pn=Phone,dob=date_of_birth,gen=gender,otp=sent)
    else:
        return render(request,"signup.html")


def otp_call(request,**kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        trials = 0
        while trials<3:
            input_otp= request.POST["six_digit"]
            if input_otp == otp:
                signedup_user = User.objects.create_user(
                    username=un,
                    password=pswrd,
                    email=mail,
                    first_name=fn,
                    last_name =ln,
                    phone_no=pn,
                    date_of_birth=dob,
                    gender= gen
                )
                signedup_user.save()
                break
                return redirect('login')       
            if input_otp != otp:
                trials+=1
                messages.error(request,"wrong otp")
                return render(request,'otp_recieve.html')
    else: 
        return render(request,'otp_recieve.html')
```

'''

I have html to confirm the otp with post request and csrf_token but I its not a right way I know because Urls.py will be needing parameeters too how do I verify users using otp through there mobile and the otp() in signup() is just a random 6 digit key generator please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the otp generated to your backend in request body as payload from front end. You can write a ajax call to do this

Then two access the data from backed , just

```
import requests
otp=req['otp']
```

Comment: Mark this as answer , if it answers your question

Comment: i am a complete beginer how do I do it exactly help!

Comment: use this refrence https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgnPSmrQrXI